# Iterating/processing a list of Tokens parsed in ANTLR

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr3, antlrworks

I have a rule

```
((cns=IDENT '->')* IDENT | (cns=IDENT '->')* 'STOP') -> ^(PREFIX ^(EVENTS $cns*) ^(ENDS $procn? STOP?)  )
```

This will work correctly if `cns=IDENT` is replaced by 'cns+=IDENT'. In that case how can I access  `cns` as `$cns.text`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store all IDENTs and not only last one `cns=IDENT` has to be changed to `cns+=IDENT`.

Now if you explore parser Java code generated by ANTLR `cns` is a generic `ArrayList` where all stored items are of type `Token`.

Now this list can be iterated through using a loop and you can do anything with the items using code like

```
$cns.get(index)
```

This item is of Object type though and can be Casted(is this correct terminology?) to `Token` object for `Token`  specific tasks.